# Python extension for Upskirt: garbage at end of string

Tags: python, c, python-extensions

I've been trying to make a Python extension for [Upskirt](https://github.com/tanoku/upskirt). I though it would not be *too* hard for a first C project since there are examples (example program in the Upskirt code and the Ruby extension).

The extension works, it converts the Markdown I throw at it, but sometimes the output has some garbage at the end of the string. And I don't know what causes it.

Here's some output:

```
python test.py 
<module 'pantyshot' from '/home/frank/Code/pantyshot/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pantyshot.so'>
<built-in function render>

'<p>This <strong>is</strong> <em>a</em> <code>test</code>. <a href="http://example.com">Test</a>.</p>\n\x7f'
<p>This <strong>is</strong> <em>a</em> <code>test</code>. <a href="http://example.com">Test</a>.</p>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'<p>This <strong>is</strong> <em>a</em> <code>test</code>. <a href="http://example.com">Test</a>.</p>\n\x7f'
<p>This <strong>is</strong> <em>a</em> <code>test</code>. <a href="http://example.com">Test</a>.</p>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My code can be found in [my Github repo](https://github.com/FSX/pantyshot). I called it pantyshot, because I thought of that when I heard upskirt. Strange name, I know.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a [`strdup` in `pantyshot_render`](https://github.com/FSX/pantyshot/blob/master/pantyshot.c#L36):

```
output_text = strdup(ob->data); /* ob is a "struct buf *" */
```

But I don't think `ob->data` is a nul-terminated C string. You'll find this inside [`upskirt/buffer.c`](https://github.com/FSX/pantyshot/blob/master/upskirt/buffer.c#L166):

```
/* bufnullterm • NUL-termination of the string array (making a C-string) */
void
bufnullterm(struct buf *buf) {
    if (!buf || !buf->unit) return;
    if (buf->size < buf->asize && buf->data[buf->size] == 0) return;
    if (bufgrow(buf, buf->size + 1))
        buf->data[buf->size] = 0; }
```

So, you're probably running off the end of the buffer and getting lucky by hitting a `'\0'` before doing any damage. I think you're supposed to call `bufnullterm(ob)` before copying `ob->data` as a C string; or you could look at [`ob->size`](https://github.com/FSX/pantyshot/blob/master/upskirt/buffer.h#L33), use `malloc` and `strncpy` to copy it, and take care of the nul-terminator by hand (but make sure you allocation `ob->size + 1` bytes for your copied string).

And if you want to get rid of the newline (i.e. the trailing `\n`), then you'll probably have to do some whitespace stripping by hand somewhere.